# How to hide div if option selected jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a div if the option with the class:fixed1 is selected.
If it is not selected show this div using jquery.

```
<script>
    if ('.fixed1'.selected)
       $('.hideIfFixed').css('display','none');
     else
       $('.hideIfFixed').css('display','block');
</script>
```

Comment: Share your HTML also

Comment: <option value="fixed" class="fixed1" {{ $voucher->duration_type === 'fixed' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Fixed</option>
                            <option value="cron" class="cron1" {{ $voucher->duration_type === 'cron' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Cron</option>

<div class="row hideIfFixed">HELLO</div>

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal CHECK ABOVE thanks

Comment: @ILOVEBEER420 if you look below the tags on your question, there is an `edit` link.  Click that and add your markup to the question, not the comments.

Comment: Also `if ('.fixed1'.selected)` <-- can you tell me what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @ILOVEBEER420 added a answer based on your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `onchange` event for the `select` dropdown:

```js
function changeSelect(elem){
  if ($(elem).find('option:selected').hasClass('fixed1'))
    $('.hideIfFixed').css('display','none');
  else
   $('.hideIfFixed').css('display','block');
}
```

```css
.hideIfFixed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange='changeSelect(this)'>
  <option value="fixed" class="fixed1">Fixed</option>
  <option value="cron" class="cron1">Cron</option> 
</select>
<div class="row hideIfFixed">HELLO</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on jQuery a bit more, your syntax is quite off.

Are you trying to do this on initial page load? Or are you hoping that each time the item is selected or deselected the DOM is updated?

For the former, only on page load:

```
$(function () {
  if ($('.fixed1').is(':selected')) {
    $('.hideIfFixed').hide();
  } else {
    $('.hideIfFixed').show();
  }
});
```

For the latter, on each interaction, you will need to use the `<select>`, rather than the `<option>`. So, let's say your `<select>` has the class `fixed1select`:

```
$(function () {
  $('.fixed1select').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).find('.fixed1').is(':selected')) {
      $('.hideIfFixed').hide();
    } else {
      $('.hideIfFixed').show();
    }
  }
});
```